# Fixed workout routine (for 6 weeks) vs day-to-day variable routine?

Tags: muscle, workout-routines, bodybuilding, hypertrophy, crossfit

There are tons of videos from fitness experts who recommend that you follow a fixed program for an average of about 6 weeks to maximize muscle growth. And this is also the philosophy with which I have seen personal trainers draw up training schedules in my gym. The idea behind that is, as far as I know, to let the muscles get used to the stimuli before changing exercises

A few weeks ago I started Crossfit (because I like its variety, the fact that it is done in a group of people and the fact that I can train many exercises in the same period of time, without having to abandon some to focus on a few) which makes use, like many other sports, a workout that is not exactly fixed like an ordinary bodybuilding program, but which changes from one training session to another. I am therefore curious to know the following: **for the purposes of muscle growth, what is the impact of following a fixed training program for 6 weeks vs a training program that varies from session to session, provided that both programs bring the athlete to failure?**

And, finally, I'd like to add 1-2 sessions per week of bodybuilding exercises. Do you think I should follow a fixed routine (4-6 weeks) for them or just vary like for the crossfit routine?

Comment: Consistency is key to getting stronger.
In order to be consistent you need to keep track of what you are doing so that you make sure that you actually lift say 2.5 kg more every week.
Constantly changing the exercises make this difficult.
I would train crossfit 1 or 2 a week for the fun of it, and follow a fixed program by myself 1 or 2 a week.
In this fixed program I would do a subset of the crossfit exercises involving the most muscle mass.
For instance deadlift, front squat, shoulder press and pull ups. I would also do bench press.